# How to run multiple pipelines with appsrc in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I've got running already a working gstreamer pipeline in an embedded C linux application. The pipeline looks like this:

appsrc-> queue - > h264encode -> queue -> h264parse -> mp4mux -> filesink

The source is a video memory buffer which is pushed into a appscr element using the "need-data" standard method.

The code is similar to the gstreamer examples and looks like this:

```
static void
cb_need_data (GstElement *appsrc,
          guint       unused_size,
          gpointer    user_data)
{
  static gboolean white = FALSE;
  static GstClockTime timestamp = 0;
  GstBuffer *buffer;
  guint size;
  GstFlowReturn ret;

  size = 1024 * 768 * 2;

  buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc (size);

  /* this makes the image black/white */
  memset (buffer->data, white ? 0x55 : 0xaa, size);

  white = !white;

  GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP (buffer) = timestamp;
  GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, 2);

  timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer);

  g_print("push-buffer\n");
  //g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
  ret = gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), buffer);

  if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
    /* something wrong, stop pushing */
    g_print("ret fail\n");
    g_main_loop_quit (loop);
  }
}

gint
main (gint   argc,
      gchar *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *appsrc;

  /* init GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  /* setup pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch("appsrc name=mysource ! fakesink silent=0", NULL);

  appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name_recurse_up (GST_BIN (element), "source");

  GstCaps *caps = gst_video_format_new_caps(GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_UYVY, 1024, 768, 0, 1, 4, 3);
  gst_app_src_set_caps(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), caps);

  /* setup appsrc */
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc),
        "stream-type", 0,
        "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL);
  g_signal_connect (appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (cb_need_data), NULL);

  /* play */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  g_print("PLAY\n");
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  /* clean up */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
  g_main_loop_unref (loop);

  return 0;
}
```

Now I need to run multiple identical pipelines in parallel. Since the pipeline elements will be identical, I'm planning to create a data structure containing all necessary gstreamer elements, like that I should be able to create different instances of the same pipeline type:

```
appsrc1-> ...... -> filesink1
appsrc2-> ...... -> filesink2
appsrc3-> ...... -> filesink3
.....
```

**The question:**

The problem is that I don't know how to instantiate the  `cb_need_data` callback function for each the different `appsrc` elements, would it be possible to instantiate this function?  Or do I need to create a copy for each pipeline? (cb_need_data1, cb_need_data2,...etc )

Comment: You can reuse the same function for all three.

Comment: Hi,  if I do it so, could the pipelines be executed in parallel? Or would they do it on a queue (serial)?

Comment: In parallel if the sources run in parallel. This is just a C callback function. It is just a location of code that is run. It is not an instance or anything weird.